# skip last 10 rows for read in csv file (unknown number of rows)

Tags: r, csv

i knew that there is options `skip` for `read.csv()`

I knew how to do for skip first 10 rows as follow:

```
data2<-read.csv("book4.csv", skip=10, header=T)
```

How about for skipping last 10 rows?

My approach is

```
data2 <- data2[1:(dim(data2)[1]-10),]
```

Is there any alternative way?

Thanks

Comment: Use `readLines` to figure out how many lines there are and then `read.csv` on the result, less the last 10 lines.

Comment: btw, you can save a few keystrokes: `data2[1:(nrow(data2)-10),]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As @Thomas suggested you can combine `readLines` and `read.csv`, e.g.:

```
df <- read.csv(text=paste0(head(readLines("file.csv"), -10), collapse="\n"))
```

But I am not sure that this approach is better than your `data2 <- data2[1:(dim(data2)[1]-10),]`. It would be the better approach if your last 10 lines are in a different format and break `read.csv`.

Comment: I am having a similar problem with a txt file that in first 300 rows includes SQL errors and they don't allow to read the columns of this I used skip=300 but it doesn't work. Is it possible to read this file @sgibb Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Try tihs:

```
data2 <- head(data2, -10)
```