# read.table and drop last few lines (R)

Tags: r, rows, read.table

I'm trying to convert stuff from a text file into a data frame in R. I want to skip the first three lines, and then only read until the line above `*End` using read.table like so:

```
df <- read.table("file.txt", sep = ",", dec = ".", skip = 3, nrows = length("file.txt")-2)
```

but I get this error:

```
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
line 8 did not have 4 elements
```

data looks like this:

```
*Keyword
*Node
$ Node,X,Y,Z
1,977201.91822656,3678881.46362572,0
2,977200.22079647,3678888.57347347,0
3,977198.87254619,3678898.82239956,0
4,977191.95056633,3679152.85114021,0
*End
```

Comment: Can you just assume that `*` is the comment character? That way you can skip them with `comment="*"`

Comment: Otherwise possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23080554/skip-last-10-rows-for-read-in-csv-file-unknown-number-of-rows